# Error when using G-Suite Developer console with Google Sites embedded API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sites

I've written some code that retrieves some data from google sheets then updates some content on my google sites. However, while the script works (when run on localhost) I encounter the

```
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: https://966655698-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com has not been whitelisted for client ID MY-ID. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
```

However, I enabled this for localhost, cleared my caches. The problem is the 'https://966655698-atari-embeds'. Each time the google site loads it generates a new random number sequence. Does anyone know how to workaround this? The google site uses embedded html which I believe is why the initialization failed.

I have tried to white-list https://googleusercontent.com which didn't work (I didn't think it would because the domain changes) but I'm honestly incredibly stumped.

Comment: Not the best idea, but did you try whitelisting using a wildcard like `*`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that's not possible with google's developer console. What I had to do was host it using github pages and simply embed it. Shame that's how this ended up having to work.

Answer (score 0):

Google hosts all user content using their somedomain.googleusercontent.com. I do not know for certain, but I'm almost sure that to save space they dynamically host their content, meaning that when the embedded html does not need to be actively hosted, it isn't. I had to find a way to host from a site that would always send the request. For me, I found that github pages was the answer.

I found this on adobe's website which somewhat explains what googleusercontent does. https://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/googleusercontentcom-instances.html

To set up github pages this link will explain how to do so https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

You can add this to the developer Google console relatively easily and any connection will submit from your username.github.io. (I believe it also uses https protocol). It also allows me to implement directly using git version control and implements nicely with WebStorm.